# Comparing NodeJS buffers while avoiding timing attacks

Tags: javascript, node.js, security, timing

I'm writing an application with NodeJS that uses two Base64 encoded tokens to authenticate users. The two tokens, when XORed, should match a third token that is stored in a database.

This is what I have now:

```
function verifyTokens(encodedTokens) {
    var similarity = 0;
    var buffers = encodedTokens.map(base64.decode);
    for (i = 0; i < TOKEN_LENGTH; i++) {
        if ((buffers[0][i] ^ buffers[1][i]) === buffers[2][i]) {
            similarity += 1;
        }
    }
    return (similarity === TOKEN_LENGTH);
}
```

I believe this is unsafe against timing attacks, because adding 1 to `similarity` probably takes more time than doing nothing. I also have no idea how safe the JavaScript equality operator is.

Another solution for working with buffers that caught my eye is [node-buffertools](https://github.com/bnoordhuis/node-buffertools/blob/master/buffertools.cc), but it uses `memcmp` to compare buffers (which I understand isn't safe).

What is the best way to compare two XORed buffers with a third buffer that avoids timing attacks? I'd prefer a JavaScript-only solution over a C++ extension.

Comment: Don't know the answer to "the best way to compare two XORed buffers", but you could spend the extra time before returning. Isn't this feasible?

Comment: Yes, I also plan to delay the authentication response. I'm not sure it is enough in itself to counter timing attacks, even if the delay is random.

Comment: Yeah I am imagining doing some testing to find out how long the XOR operation takes, and adding a setTimeout wrapper that ensures that the function returns after some longer time (in both cases)

Comment: Also, besides the question, what authentication method is it? A link with specs might be useful (this would be for my personal curiosity / benefit)

Comment: The method is similar to http://www.ucrec.org/pubs/upload/836_van%20der%20Horst2008.pdf

Comment: See [Node Issue #8560 - Crypto library should have a constant-time equality function](https://github.com/joyent/node/issues/8560)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could add the resulting boolean instead:

```
function verifyTokens(encodedTokens) {
    var buffers = encodedTokens.map(base64.decode);
    var similarity = 0;

    for (var i = 0; i < TOKEN_LENGTH; i++) {
        similarity += (buffers[0][i] ^ buffers[1][i]) === buffers[2][i]);
    }

    return similarity === TOKEN_LENGTH;
}
```

Although V8 might optimize this and skew the results. You can test for that yourself. I'd test `encodedTokens.map(base64.decode)` first.

Comment: This looks like a good improvement to me. How should I approach testing for timing attack vectors? Is a simple repeated benchmark accurate enough or is reading the source code the only thorough option?

Comment: @molf: Use a benchmark. The source probably won't be too helpful.

Answer (score 3):

```
function verifyTokens(encodedTokens) {
    var similarity = 0;
    var buffers = encodedTokens.map(base64.decode);
    for (i = 0; i < TOKEN_LENGTH; i++) {
        similarity |= (buffers[0][i] ^ buffers[1][i]) | (buffers[1][i] ^ buffers[2][i]);
    }
    return similarity === 0;
}
```

Probably the same thing, but people usually [don't trust](http://rdist.root.org/2010/01/07/timing-independent-array-comparison/) comparison operators.

Answer (score 0):

Could you XOR all three tokens and compare to zero?

```
var zeroes = new Buffer(Array(32)); // zero fills, not sure encoding
function verifyTokens(encodedTokens) {
  var buffers = encodedTokens.map(base64.decode);
  var xor1 = buffers[0] ^ buffers[1];
  var xor2 = xor1 ^ buffers[2];
  if(xor2.toString() === zeroes.toString()){
    // there may be a better comparison operator
    // buf1 === buf2 seems to always return false with different encodings
    return true;
  } else {
    return false;
  }
}
```